# Comment box will load after submission but text will not show up until I refresh - Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Jumping into a mature React App for my company but still learning the ins and outs of it. I have a comment box that when submitted, will load the text box and the css, but the actual comment doesnt show up until you refresh the page. I have tried to play around with the state logic but so far haven't been able to get anywhere. I should be able to hit submit, then see the comment show up with user who submitted it and when they submitted it. Any ideas?

Dispatch Store:

```
     public addComment(comment: string, dispatchId: string) {
        return this.api.post(`/dispatch/${dispatchId}/comment`, { 
         comment });
      }

     public async addComment(comment: string) {
        const retComment = await this.api.addComment(comment, 
          this.dispatch.id);
          runInAction(() => {
          this.dispatch.comments.unshift(retComment);
           });
           return retComment;
       }
```

Dispatch Details:

```
export class DispatchDetails extends React.Component {

public DispatchStore: DispatchStore;
public UserStore: UserStore;
private MessageStore: MessageStore;
private TestsStore: TestsStore;
private WellsStore: WellsStore;
public props: any;

private dispatchDisposer: any;

public state = {
    comment: '',
    dataTableItems: [] as any[],
    destinationWellId: '',
    disableEditing: true,
    dispatchItem: undefined as unknown as IDispatchItem,
    dispatchTruckOpen: [true] as boolean[],
    dispatchTrucks: [] as IDispatchTruck[],
    dispatchTrucksHaveEta: [] as boolean[],
    dropdownOpen: false,
    expenseList: [] as IEBPExpenseType[],
    isDirty: false,
    newExpenseList: [] as IEBPExpenseType[],
    newInventoryList: [] as IProduct[],
    newTruckIndex: -1,
    productList: [] as IProduct[],
    reallocateModal: false,
    reallocateTruckNew: undefined as unknown as IDispatchTruck,
    reallocateTruckOne: undefined as unknown as IDispatchTruck,
    reallocations: [] as IReallocation[],
    showNewTruckModal: false,
    showProductModal: false,
    statusIndex: 0,
    tab: 'product',
    wellList: [] as IWell[],
};



constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    this.DispatchStore = props.stores.DispatchStore;
    this.UserStore = props.stores.UserStore;
    this.MessageStore = props.stores.MessageStore;
    this.TestsStore = props.stores.TestsStore;
    this.WellsStore = props.stores.WellsStore;
}

public componentDidMount() {
    this.createDisposers();
    this.DispatchStore.getDispatch(this.props.match.params.dispatchId);
    this.WellsStore.getWellsNoFilter()
        .then(wellList => {
            this.setState({wellList});
    });
    this.props.stores.WellsStore.clearWell();
}

    private handleAddComment = () => {
       const comment = this.state.comment.trim();
        if (comment) {
          this.DispatchStore.addComment(comment)
            .then(data => {
                if (data) {
                    this.MessageStore.addMessage('Comment Added', 
                  'success');
                    this.setState({
                        comment: '',
                    });
                }
           });
          }
     }


       <div className="well-story">
          {   dispatch.comments &&
           dispatch.comments.map((story, index) =>
            <div key={index}>
           {story && story.comment && story.comment.split('/n').map((remark, indexRem) => {
              if(remark === '') {
               return <br key={indexRem} />;
               }
                 return <p key={indexRem} className="the-remark">{remark}</p>;
                 })
                    }
                    <p className="remark-datetime">
                     {story && story.commentBy + ' | ' + moment(story && story.commentDate, 'X').format('LLL')}
                                        </p>
                                        
                                    </div>
                                ) }
                            </div>
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                    {
                        this.UserStore.hasPermission("Permissions.Dispatch.Comment") &&
                    <React.Fragment>
                        <Row>
                            <Col>
                                <Input
                                    type="textarea"
                                    rows="3"
                                    name="comment"
                                    id="comment"
                                    value={this.state.comment}
                                    onChange={this.handleChangeComment}
                                />
                            </Col>
                        </Row>
                        <Row>
                            <Col>
                                <Button style={{margin: "1rem"}} color="primary" onClick={this.handleAddComment}>Add Comment</Button>
                                <Button className="secondary" onClick={this.clearComment}>Clear Comment</Button>
                            </Col>
                        </Row>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you are using [*react-redux*](https://react-redux.js.org/)

Given the fact that the comment is visible after being refresh, it can be inferred that the `this.DispatchStore.addComment` action and its completion handler **do not update the state of the comment list**. You need to edit your action code or response handler to **add redux store state update**

I could add some sample code if you provided the complete code for the component, the `this.DispatchStore.addComment` action, and the comment reducer

Comment: That would be great! Posted more of the code above!

Comment: @MatthewLemke your project doesn't work as i expected. Do you have the ability to show how the comment list is stored and how it is filled?

Comment: I actually figured it out, we had a built in function in the POST route to send a notification to users who have permission, that notification function was broken, thats why it would update the page, however the info was there because it had nothing to do with the actual comment.

Comment: @MatthewLemke did I understand correctly that everything is working fine now?

Comment: yessir! Thanks for the help.